# suggestion about how to read RDF using c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, owl, dotnetrdf

I'm new to the semantic web topic, and I created an ontology which I need to develop a website that can read the ontology and extract the information from the OWL file and display it in the website
I did some research about which library i need to use, So i found that RDFdotnet in the best library i need to use it for reading the owl file
also i found a code but i need some one explain or help me with this code for reading my owl file. I wanna use dropdown list and button 
please any suggestion ???

this is the code

```
//Define your Graph here - it may be better to use a QueryableGraph if you plan
//on making lots of Queries against this Graph as that is marginally more performant
IGraph g = new Graph();

//Load some data into your Graph using the LoadFromFile() extension method
g.LoadFromFile("myfile.rdf");

//Use the extension method ExecuteQuery() to make the query against the Graph
try
{
  Object results = g.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * WHERE { ?s a ?type }");
  if (results is SparqlResultSet)
  {
     //SELECT/ASK queries give a SparqlResultSet
     SparqlResultSet rset = (SparqlResultSet)results;
     foreach (SparqlResult r in rset)
     {
       //Do whatever you want with each Result
     }
  } 
  else if (results is IGraph)
  {
     //CONSTRUCT/DESCRIBE queries give a IGraph
     IGraph resGraph = (IGraph)results;
     foreach (Triple t in resGraph.Triples)
     {
        //Do whatever you want with each Triple
     }
  }
  else
  {
     //If you don't get a SparqlResutlSet or IGraph something went wrong 
     //but didn't throw an exception so you should handle it here
     Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
  }
}
catch (RdfQueryException queryEx)
{
   //There was an error executing the query so handle it here
   Console.WriteLine(queryEx.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For your ASP.NET application you probably need a more abstract model than the RDF graph that dotNetRDF produces. When you parse the OWL file you get a graph which contains a collection of triples, but for your application you probably want something more like a list or a dictionary of objects that represent the bits of the ontology you are displaying.

In the dotNetRDF API there are various methods for reading triples from the graph and you can use these to find the OWL classes and their properties. See https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Working%20with%20Graphs for more information about working with the IGraph interface. Alternatively you could extract information from the graph using SPARQL queries (see https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Querying%20with%20SPARQL).

So in summary dotNetRDF provides the tools to parse your OWL file into a graph and then to query or navigate around that graph to extract information from it. From there I think it is completely up to you about how exactly you structure the model for your application - based on your application requirements.